# Not Even Chegg could solve this - Generating Discrete Random Variable - discrete hazard rates

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, markov-chains

I have this question:

Suppose that 0 ≤ λn ≤ λ, for all n ≥ 1. Consider the following algorithm to
generate a random variable having discrete hazard rates {λn}.

- step 1: S = 0.
- step 2: Generate U and set Y = Int (log(U)/log(1−λ))+ 1.
- step 3: S = S + Y .
- step 4: Generate U.
- step 5: If U ≤ λS/λ, set X = S and stop. Otherwise, go to 2.

(a) What is the distribution of Y in Step 2?

(b) Explain what the algorithm is doing g, in terms of the iid random pairs of variables {(Yn, Un)}
where Yn ⊥ Un have distributions G_Y and U(0, 1) respectively. Show that X is a random
stopping time adapted to the natural filtration {Fn} = {σ(Yi
, Ui
;i ≤ n)}.

(c) Argue that X is a random variable with discrete hazard rates {λn}.

I believe I understand (a), where I just get the inverse function mentioned in step 2, for which I got

F^-1 = (λ-1)e^{Y+1}

but for (b) and (c) I have no idea. have been searching internet for hours...

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference